# JavaFX 2 change layout dynamically at runtime?

Tags: layout, javafx-2

Swing had LayoutManager's separate from the containers. So far as I can tell, JavaFX doesn't do that.

I have a complex structure of nodes that I want the user to be able to toggle between several different layout approaches. Something equivalent to the user specifying flow and all containers are converted to the equivalent of FlowPanes. Then they could choose vertical and everything is laid out vertically.

Is there a way to do this other than swapping out the nodes/recreating the whole structure?

I should note: the hierarchy changes at runtime and it is deeply nested.

I mention Swing because this is straightforward to do in Swing by maintaining a list of all containers in the entire hierarchy, and with a simple loop (or tree traversal without the list) setting a new LayoutManager on them. JavaFX doesn't seem to have this possibility because the layout behavior appears to be internal to the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't something like this working ?

```
AnchorPane main=new AnchorPane();
AnchorPane sub1=new AnchorPane();
sub1.getChildren().add(btn);
main.getChildren().add(sub1);
```

When you want to switch the layout

```
AnchorPane sub2=new AnchorPane();
main.getChildren().remove(sub1);
main.getChildren().add(sub2);
```

**Edit**
I guess I missed how you are doing layouts. This is how I envisioned it.

```
Definitions to Various Components
MainLayout

-> CustomLayout 1
     -> References to various components.  ( Essentially you are not creating all the components for every layout, rather you are referring to them in each layout )
-> CustomLayout 2
     -> References to various components. ( More or less a different arrangement of the same components, adds some component references and removes some )
-> CustomLayout 3
     -> References to various components.
```

Making a bold statement, but if there were a tool in JavaFX, how would it do this automatically ? Each template needs to know where it should render a particular component and arguably the easiest way to do this is just create a new template that arranges the components in a different layout and swap the template when user wants to see a different layout.

Comment: That's the "other than swapping out the nodes/recreating the whole structure" I mentioned in my question. I'd have to do what you have there to all non-leaf nodes in the tree. I was wondering if there was some lighter weight solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy to do in Swing.  You would still need to set all the layout constraints on the individual components again, unless your layout is very straightforward.

I don't see how there is much difference in this between swing and javaFX.  In JavaFX you would need to add the same controls to a different container (VBox, HBox etc.) but you still don't need to recreate the controls every time.  It is a little awkward to find the containers in the middle of the node hierarchy but I'm sure there is some kind of elegant recursive solution :)